# Connecting to API with SOAP

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I am working with PHP and I am new to SOAP and having issues understanding the basic. I have this document that explains of what I need

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/508603/api/API%20Web%20Service3.docx

I have a web form where the user enters zip code and chooses a category of service.

Then, after this form is filled out, it would need to connect to the API by sending a request through SOAP, WSDL or REST Posting call.

In the document, please go to Page#3. You will see all the URL the API can be reached on. You can choose any of these approaches.

On page#4 I would need to ping their API to see if their is a service in a given Zip Code. The "categoryID" can be found on page#10 - page#14.

On page#4 we will be testing if the user has coverage of their service or not based on the zip code entered. The zip code and the categoryid will be entered in a web form.

Then, on page#5, we have all the fieldnames that needs to be named.

On page#6 we have a POST EXAMPLE

You will also see the type of responses the api returns as well.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide me a way to make this work....

thank you

Comment: Call me paranoid, but I'm not going to open a Microsoft .docx file from somebody's Dropbox.  That seems just a tad dangerous ;)  Q: What exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly is your question?  Just "How do I do web services from PHP"?

Comment: oh sorry but the api documentation i have is too long and well explained. That's why I add it in my dropbox. You can trust me, this is no virus or whatsoever :) I just need to to make an API call with SOAp to a client server and then get a response back. But again, it is perfectly explained in the documentation. I can explain here more in case you have questions...

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid I can't open your docx file.  But let me try to be general.

Have they provided a [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) file?  That would be VERY helpful in defining the context/methods available when using their API.

PHP has a variety of [SOAP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) classes.  The one you will want is [`SoapClient`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlurl, $optionsArray);
$client->api_method_name($params);
```

Pretty straight forward.  If you provide more examples from this doc file, I can try to help out more.

Comment: @denis - St. John Johnson is correct: it should be pretty straightforward.  Here's a short, simple example on using web services from a PHP client:  http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/